# How to change map view on fragment?

Tags: android, mapbox

I'm developing an app by using mapbox api. At the map when the user clicks map item on menu a fragment is opening.Later user may want to change mapview style such as satellite,dark,emerald or just a street view. User is able to choose map style on action bar. I implemented my action bar on main activity. When the user on map fragment choose map style and a variable comes to fragment which handled in main activity. This variable is the string of map style. Now I want to change map view style without recreating map fragment. What can you advise about this problem ?

```
public class GeoMapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    public MapView mapView = null;
    private MapboxMap mapboxMap;
    public String mapViewSelectedItem ;

    private static final int PERMISSIONS_LOCATION = 0;

    public GeoMapFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_geomap, container, false);


        mapView = (MapView)view.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mapView.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mapView.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }

    /**
     * Dispatch onPause() to fragments.
     */
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(MapboxMap map) {

        mapboxMap = map;
        mapboxMap.setStyle(Style.DARK);
        mapboxMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(0, 0)));

        // Show user location (purposely not in follow mode)
        if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) ||
                (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, PERMISSIONS_LOCATION);
        } else {
            mapboxMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }

        // TODO - mv.loadFromGeoJSONURL("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/tmcw/10307131/raw/21c0a20312a2833afeee3b46028c3ed0e9756d4c/map.geojson");
        mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("Edinburgh").snippet("Scotland").position(new LatLng(55.94629, -3.20777)));
        mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("Stockholm").snippet("Sweden").position(new LatLng(59.32995, 18.06461)));
        mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("Prague").snippet("Czech Republic").position(new LatLng(50.08734, 14.42112)));
        mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("Athens").snippet("Greece").position(new LatLng(37.97885, 23.71399)));
        mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("Tokyo").snippet("Japan").position(new LatLng(35.70247, 139.71588)));
        mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("Ayacucho").snippet("Peru").position(new LatLng(-13.16658, -74.21608)));
        mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("Nairobi").snippet("Kenya").position(new LatLng(-1.26676, 36.83372)));
        mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("Canberra").snippet("Australia").position(new LatLng(-35.30952, 149.12430)));

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSIONS_LOCATION: {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    mapboxMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your map fragment should have a `getMapAsync()` call which you can change the style of. Heres a rough example of how you can accomplish this:

```
private MapboxMap map;

...

mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(final MapboxMap mapboxMap) {

            map = mapboxMap;

        }
    });

...

// Wherever you implemented receiving the style string from MainActivity you can include this:

map.setStyleUrl(<style url>);
```

If this doesn't work for you, please let me know how exactly you are creating the map fragment. Currently the SDK includes a fragment already which you can setup like so:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        LatLng patagonia = new LatLng(-52.6885, -70.1395);

        MapboxMapOptions options = new MapboxMapOptions();
        options.accessToken("<your access token here>");
        options.styleUrl(Style.SATELLITE);
        options.camera(new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(patagonia)
                .zoom(9)
                .build());

        mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance(options);

        transaction.add(R.id.container, mapFragment, "mapFragment");
        transaction.commit();
    } else {
        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("mapFragment");
    }

    mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(final MapboxMap mapboxMap) {

            map = mapboxMap;

        }
    });
}
```

If you did it this way you can easily change the style of the map like I said above.

Hope this helps out!

Comment: I have updated my code. You can have a look my fragment and using map.

Comment: So how can i change mapstyle from selecting actionbar ?

Comment: I think you'll need to create an interface to pass the string from your activity to fragment. It would be much easier implementing the mapFragment like I suggested in my answer. All your code shown will work the same and you can directly change the map style.

Comment: sorry but i couldn't do that. the mapfragment has already created. User can choose a style from action bar onOptionsItemSelected is called so do i need to replacing fragment or where do write your code on my fragment